# Filter objects and empty a column, django

Tags: python, django

I have a queryset like this

```
Entries.objects.filter(some="1")
```

For each object I want to empty a column named "example" like this

```
Entries.objects.filter(some="1").example.empty()
```

Can someone help me to achieve this

Comment: By empty a column you mean show that column in result and show as Null or don't show at all?

Comment: Did you mean `Entries.objects.filter(some=1).update(example="")`?